# Left indent Crystal Reports text field from second paragraph line

Tags: crystal-reports, text-formatting, text-indent

If you have text field that can grow over multiple lines, is it possible to indent the paragraph starting from the second line?

You can define a first line, left and right indent. I want to insert a negative number for the first line indent as that's actually what I wanted to achieve. It's showing me an error message saying the I have to enter a number between 0 and 11.75.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very confusing, but I've finally figured it out.

You actually can insert a negative first line indent. What the error message doesn't tell you is that the lowest possible value depends on the left indent.
You can set a negative left indent, allowing the first line indent to be negative as well.

It appears that a negative left indent can't be applied, but a negative first line indent forces CR to manipulate the dimensions of the field in order to apply the negative first line indent.

So a field with a width of 200 and a negative first line and left indent of 0.5
results in a box of 200px + 0.5cm with a indent starting at the second line of 0.5cm

Example without any indent

```
A. text on first line
text on second line
text on third line
```

Example with -0,85 left indent and -0,85 first line indent:

```
A. text on first line
   text on second line
   text on third line
```